# Is there a cost to repeating a $watch for the same variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

I have some textAngular code where I watch a variable in the scope, multiple times?  Is there a simple way to only create this watch once, or can I detect that it exists???

The section of code is:

```
 taRegisterTool('fontColor', {
    display: "<button colorpicker type='button' class='btn btn-default ng-scope'  title='Font Color'  colorpicker-close-on-select colorpicker-position='bottom' ng-model='fontColor' style='color: {{fontColor}}'><i class='fa fa-font '></i></button>",
    action: function (deferred) {
      var self = this;
      self.$watch('fontColor', function (newValue) {
        self.$editor().wrapSelection('foreColor', newValue);
      });
      self.$on('colorpicker-selected', function () {
        deferred.resolve();
      });
      self.$on('colorpicker-closed', function () {
        deferred.resolve();
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Each time this button is clicked, this action is executed.  This $watch causes multiple instances to be created and to live on.

Based on the helpful comment by 'npe' below, I have amended the code to keep the watch from being created multiple times.

New Code:

```
taRegisterTool('fontColor', {
        display: "<button colorpicker type='button' class='btn btn-default ng-scope'  title='Font Color'  colorpicker-close-on-select colorpicker-position='bottom' ng-model='fontColor' style='color: {{fontColor}}'><i class='fa fa-font '></i></button>",
        action: function (deferred) {
          var self = this;
          if (typeof self.listener == 'undefined') {
            self.listener = self.$watch('fontColor', function (newValue) {
              console.log(newValue);
              self.$editor().wrapSelection('foreColor', newValue);
            });
          }
          self.$on('colorpicker-selected', function () {
            deferred.resolve();
          });
          self.$on('colorpicker-closed', function () {
            deferred.resolve();
          });
          return false;
        }
      });
```

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Why not just add a `console.log` inside watch function, and see how many times it's evaluated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to the question is as easy as putting a single line of logging code in the code the OP already provided. This shows lack of effort put into finding the answer itself.

Comment: If I put a console.log() message here, I it is CLEAR that is will only be called when the 'fontColor' is changed.  AND this is not an issue!  since this will happen only when the user has changed the color.  BUT the question is what does the angular implementation do under the covers.  I would like to understand that.  I am not worried about the code on a click!!!  Perhaps you are suggesting that if I don't end up with multiple log messages, then this perhaps will answer the question which is insightful.  I will report back.

Comment: So as I suspected, each time a fontColor is changed, a new $watch is added, and I seem n+1 log messages each time. Thanks for the insight. I will amend my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and suggested addition of a log message from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1344008/npe, it is clear that in this instance the watch is created multiple times which I understood, and by looking at the log output: It is clear that every watch is added and even if exactly the same variable is watched, one needs to keep track of the listener which is returned when it is added in order to remove it.  This makes complete sense... I just wasn't thinking so clearly :-) So I amended the code to remove this inefficiency.  Thanks to those that looked at this.